# [Arduino UNO]Receive Serial Data from multiple sources

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I have the following system:

[image]

As a master, I have an Arduino UNO Chip, more specifically an Atmel MEGA328P. The important thing is that this microcontroller has only one hardware Serial port, and that port is used to communicate with a WiFi adapter.

The problem I'm facing with is that I want to receive data from a Compass and a GPS modules. Booth send data via Serial protocol. The 328p Chip have only one serial which is busy!

**I can't use SoftwareSerial as I don't want any delay on master board!**
I can't also use Arduino Mega2560 which have 3 Serial ports as its sizes are too big.

So there are are my approaches:

1. Using MCP4725 I2C DAC for Compass, but what we do with GPS?
2. Using and intermediate Arduino UNO Chip?
   On that chip I could use Software serial but how to transfer data to MASTER using only digital and analogic pins? Maybe using 10 pins to implement a parallel transfer?
3. Perhaps there is possible to convert Compass and GPS data to analogic then transfer to MASTER?

Anyway, what possibilities would I have to play around?

Comment: That was a lot of design restrictions. You might want to look at an I2C/SPI to UART bridge; http://www.nxp.com/products/interface-and-connectivity/interface-and-system-management/bridges/i2c-spi-slave-to-uart-irda-gpio-bridges:MC_51852

Comment: Maybe you should consider stepping away from Arduino boards and exploring the plethora of more capable boards that are out there - most of which can be programmed with the Arduino IDE using the Arduino API.

Comment: You chose the wrong part.  Lots of ARM Cortex parts have 3 UARTs, some of them have Arduino ports.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Only 3? I'm used to working with chips that have 6 UARTs... ;)

Comment: @Majenko : Can you guys provide some links please? It would be very usefully :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/26240/which-pins-of-an-arduino-uno-can-be-used-as-tx-and-rx-pins-for-connecting-to-gsm/26277#26277) summarizes the possibilities:

1) `HardwareSerial` is always best.  You are using that for WiFi.

2) [`AltSoftSerial`](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/AltSoftSerial) is the best software serial library, but it requires pins 8 & 9.  Very efficient and non-blocking!  Strongly recommended for the GPS connection.

3) [`NeoSWSerial`](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoSWSerial) is next best, but it supports only 9600, 19200 and 38400.  It is non-blocking on receive, so it could be used for the GPS connection.

4) `SoftwareSerial` is the worst.  :P  Not suitable for the GPS connection, as you have discovered.

I'll also mention my GPS library, [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS).  It is smaller and faster than other libraries, and there are examples that show how to make it run *during* the RX character interrupt, saving even more time.  It can also be configured for just the messages and fields that you actually use, saving RAM, program space and execution time.

Answer (score 0):

I think softserials are working based pinchange interrupt. This wont make you any significant delay i hop.Or you should go gps or wifi modules with SPI or IIC interface.

Comment: SoftwareSerial uses PCINT to *start* reception. During reception it blocks all other operations. That causes significant delays, especially at lower baud rates.