# SoftwareSerial data not available

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-ide, softwareserial

Second time I'm asking the same question with no solution, let me elaborate in other way for clarity.

I wrote an Arduino program which uses two serial ports, one is hardware serial port and other is SoftwareSerial port.

No problem with hardware serial port, the problem is with software serial port.

The software serial port's Tx pin works but Rx pin does not work, i.e. `portone.available()` is always zero, nothing in the input buffer of the software serial port.

I'm using Arduino IDE 1.6.12 with an Uno board. Previously I used version 1.6.9 but neither works. Here is the piece of code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

String code = "", customer = "";
bool complete = false;
byte c = 0, j = 0;
char customercode[27];
SoftwareSerial portone(10, 11);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  portone.begin(115200);
  pinMode(10, INPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  if (Serial) {
    Serial.print("Connecting");
  }    
}

void loop() {
  String copy = "";
  char inchar = '0';

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    while (Serial.available()) {
      char bytes = (char)Serial.read();
      if (bytes == '1' || bytes == '2' || bytes == '3' || bytes == '4' || bytes == '5' || bytes == '6' || bytes == '7' || bytes == '8' || bytes == '9' || bytes == '0' || bytes == '.' || bytes == '-' && bytes != '#') {
        customercode[c] = bytes;
        c++;
      } else if (bytes == '#') {
        complete = true;
      }
      if (c > 12 && bytes != '#') {
        code += bytes;
      }
    }

    if (c == 13) {
      customer += '+';
      for (byte i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        customer += customercode[i];    
      }
    }
  }
  portone.listen();
  if (portone.available() > 0) {
    portone.println("AT+CMGF=1");
    portone.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0");
    portone.flush();

    while (portone.available()) {
      inchar = (char)portone.read();
      copy += inchar;
    }
    delay(1);
    Serial.print(copy);

  } else if (complete == true && customercode != "" && code != "") {
    sending();    
  }
  Serial.print(portone.available());
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: SoftwareSerial is pretty low performance, and 115200 bps is probably asking too much. Can you lower the baud rate? Can you search the Internet for alternative implementations of a software serial port?

Comment: before I was using the 9600 baudrate but nothing happened that is why I decided to change, also I searched a lot in internet but I end up no solution. that is why I decided to come back again.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `portone.listen()`.  That method is only necessary when you have created *multiple* `SoftwareSerial` ports.  It specifies which port you are listening to, because only one of them can receive at a time (you can transmit on any of them at any time).  It also *empties the receive buffer* so that data from one `SoftwareSerial` port is not mistakenly returned by another.  In your code, this empties the input buffer before checking `portone.available()`.  Surprise, it's always empty!  ;)

Also, don't set the pin mode of the pins used for the `SoftwareSerial` object.  The pin modes were set during the constructor of `portone`, which happens before `setup`.  You're messing with pins that have been "promised" to that library for its own use and control.

As Edgar suggested, you should consider a more-efficient software serial library.  AltSoftSerial is best, but is only available on certain pins.  My [NeoSWSerial](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoSWSerial) library is next best, and works on any two pins, but only at 9600, 19200 and 38400.  Both of those libraries can transmit and receive at the same time, unlike `SoftwareSerial`.  [Here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/26240#26277) is an answer with all the gory details.

And you really should ditch the `String` class usage.  You obviously know how to use `char` arrays (aka "C strings").  We can't see the `sending()` function, but you can probably just print a few pieces instead of building a complete `String` and printing it:

```
    portone.print( '+' ); // leading plus sign
    portone.write( (uint8_t *) customerCode, 13 ); // array of bytes, length
```

It would be better to terminate the character arrays with a zero byte (NUL-termination) in `loop` so they can be used as a standard C string instead of a byte array:

```
    customerCode[14] = '\0'; // NUL-terminate the C string
```

Then you can use the standard C string `print` in `sending`:

```
    portone.print( '+' ); // leading plus sign
    portone.print( customerCode );
```

Printing the pieces is always more efficient than building a big buffer with all the pieces.  This avoids copying the pieces and needing twice as much RAM.     :P

Comment: `portone.print(code)` is printing to the GSM module, then how can I control message so that it prints by iterations of peace wise message  while the full message should reach the receiver, and to control the iterations on receiving the message from the GSM module peace wise between the input buffer of an arduino and GSM, as it is sent full.

Comment: @kassim, if I understand your question, I think you are asking about calling `print` several times instead of just once.  The GSM does not see how many `print` calls were made, just that a certain number of characters were sent.  Because it takes about 1ms per char, the Arduino is able to start sending the second piece (i.e., customerCode ) almost immediately (~ 0.001ms) after the '+' character.  The GSM will not notice that tiny pause.  It will see an *almost* continuous stream of chars.  It is probably accumulating chars from the Arduino in the same way as `loop` accumulates `customerCode`.

Comment: I think the problem was library because I had added `AltSoftwareSerial` library now is fine.