# What's the difference between all the Software Serial Libraries? Which one is Arduino Nano compatible?

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, uart

There are so many Software Serial Libraries, what are the differences between them? And which one I can use with my Arduino Nano? For my Arduino Nano I need one Hardware Serial Port and one Software Serial port at a baud rate of 115200.

On which pins of the Arduino Nano can I use the software serial library?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[This answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/26240/which-pins-of-an-arduino-uno-can-be-used-as-tx-and-rx-pins-for-connecting-to-gsm/26277#26277) lists the 4 basic choices:

- `HardwareSerial`, always the best.  Simply use the pre-defined `Serial` variable.  On some Arduinos, there are extra HardwareSerial ports, called `Serial1`, `Serial2`, etc.  The Nano only has `Serial`.
- [`AltSoftSerial`](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_AltSoftSerial.html), the best of the software serial libraries.  Only one instance is allowed, and it is must be used on one of the Input Capture pins (pins 8 & 9 for a Nano).
- My [`NeoSWSerial`](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoSWSerial) is next best.  It works on any two pins, but only at baud rates 9600, 19200 and 38400.
- `SoftwareSerial` is the worst choice.  It works on any two pins, but it is very inefficient.  It disables interrupts for the entire time that a character is being sent **OR** received, and it cannot do both at the same time (unlike all the other serial choices).  This can interfere with other parts of your sketch, other device communications, or with libraries.

If you could use a slower baud rate, you could keep your debug prints on `Serial`, and use either `AltSoftSerial` or `NeoSWSerial` for your device.

But if you have to use 115200, the only reliable choice is `Serial`.  Although `AltSoftSerial` and `SoftwareSerial` allow that baud rate, they may not send/receive data correctly.

In that case, I would suggest using `Serial` for the 115200 device.  Unless you are using an ISP, you will have to disconnect the device to upload a new sketch over USB.

Then use `AltSoftSerial` or `NeoSWSerial` for your debug statements.  You will need a TTL Serial-to-USB adapter (aka FTDI) on the selected pins to connect to the PC.  The `Serial Monitor` or other [Terminal emulator program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) will read from that USB COM port.

Comment: Is AltSoftSerial the same in performance and characteristics, only that NeoICSerial adds the functionality of what? I did not understand completely. https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoICSerial

Comment: @WilliamRoy, `NeoICSerial` just adds the `attachInterrupt` method to `AltSoftSerial`.  You probably don't need to handle each character in an interrupt.  Just use `AltSoftSerial` and call the `available()` and then `read()` if a char is ready.  Similarly, `NeoHWSerial` adds the same `attachInterrupt` feature to the core `HardwareSerial`.  However, `NeoSWSerial` is a completely different class (it also has the `attachInterrupt` feature).

Comment: "SoftwareSerial is the worst choice". I think at the moment it is improved, based on Neo. If you have time please update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: both NeoSW and AltSoft cannot work with ISR vectors.