# HM-10 send and receive data and checking received value

Tags: arduino-ide, bluetooth, softwareserial, arduino-leonardo, atmega32u4

I am wondering what is wrong with my code below. I have 2 issues.

The first issue, I am checking if **c** equals "hi" and if it does then display **said hi**. I currently see the output of **c** when it hits `Serial.println(c);` but never see the **said hi** even though `Serial.println(c);` does say "said hi".

The second issue is that when I start up the Arduino I am sending the `AT` command using `bluetooth.println("AT");`, but all it seems to do is display `AT` on the phone instead of `OK` as it should.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(8,9); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.println("PC Side Connected");
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
  while (!bluetooth) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  bluetooth.println("Bluetooth Side Connected");
  bluetooth.println("AT"); // just a check
}

void loop() { // run over and over
  String c;
  if (bluetooth.available()) {
    //What is sent back from the BT module
    c = bluetooth.readStringUntil('\n');
    delay(10);
    Serial.println(c);
    if (c.equals('hi')) {
      Serial.println("said hi");
    }
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    //Send back data to Bluetooth module
    bluetooth.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with reading it just checking the value within the if statement.

Comment: @AltAir Why? `.read()` reads a single char not a string.

Comment: Could you edit the question and include the exact output please?

Comment: @MarkSmith picture added in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

> The first issue, I am checking if c equals "hi" and if it does then display said hi.

This is *not* how you compare:

```
  if (c.equals('hi')) {
```

Single quotes indicate a single (or multi-byte) character.  A character string (lower-case) is enclosed by double quotes:

```
  if (c == "hi") {
```

But it's better to avoid the `String` class (more info [here](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/)).

To eliminate the `String` class, use `char` arrays instead (aka "C strings") and accumulate characters until the newline is received.  There are many, many C string functions for manipulating and searching.  In this specific case, you would use [strcmp](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html#ga46f3cbd2de457c0fb340a1f379fc33ba) or [strstr](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html#ga6a441da9211eb85881d99c60b1003552) for comparison:

```
#include <AltSoftSerial.h>

AltSoftSerial bluetooth; // pin 8 is RX, pin 9 is TX

char btResponse[ 20 ];
uint8_t count;
const uint8_t BT_MAX = sizeof(btResponse);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("PC Side Connected");
  bluetooth.begin(9600);

  bluetooth.println("Bluetooth Side Connected");
  bluetooth.println("AT"); // just a check
}

void loop()
{
  if (bluetooth.available()) {
    // Read what is sent back from the BT module
    char c = bluetooth.read();

    if (c == '\n') {
      btResponse[ count ] = '\0'; // NUL-terminate the character array

      // Use C string functions to parse the response

      if (strcmp( btResponse, "hi" ) == 0) {
        Serial.println("only said hi");

      } else if (strstr( btResponse, "hi" ) != nullptr) {
        Serial.println("said hi, among other things...");

      }

      // And if there is a comma in there somewhere, display all comma-separated fields
      if (strchr( btResponse, ',' ) != nullptr) {
        uint8_t fieldNumber = 0;

        char *field = strtok( btResponse, "," );
        while (field != nullptr) {

          Serial.print( "Field " );
          Serial.print( fieldNumber );
          Serial.print( " = " );
          Serial.println( field );

          // Some fields might be numbers.  Parse them into integers.
          if ( isdigit( field[0] ) ) {
            int value = atoi( field );
            Serial.print( "  value = " );
            Serial.println( value );
          }

          // get next field
          field = strtok( nullptr, "," );
          fieldNumber++;
        }
      }

      // Reset the counter to receive another response
      count = 0;

    } else if (c >= ' ') {
      // Accumulate another non-control char, if there's room
      if (count < BT_MAX-1) {
        btResponse[ count++ ] = c;
      }
    }
  }

  if (Serial.available()) {
    // Send data to Bluetooth module
    bluetooth.write( Serial.read() );
  }
}
```

Notice that it shows how to use [strtok](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html#ga6ace85338eafe22a0ff52c00eb9779b8) to break the response string into individual fields, if a comma character is somewhere in the line.  For example, entering this:

```
hi,123,456
```

... produces this output:

```
said hi, among other things...
Field 0 = hi
Field 1 = 123
  value = 123
Field 2 = 456
  value = 456
```

It also uses `AltSoftSerial` for the BT connection.  `SoftwareSerial` is very inefficient, and it cannot send and receive at the same time.  It will lose received data while it is transmitting to the BT.  This can also interfere with other parts of your sketch or other libraries.

[This answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34126#34130) has a good summary of the alternatives and how to select one.  Since you are already using pins 8 & 9, it would be easy to switch to the `AltSoftSerial` library.  All of the mentioned libraries are available from the Arduino IDE Library Manager, under the menu **Sketch -> Include Library -> Manage Libraries**.