# Make Arduino send and receive at the same time

Tags: gsm, softwareserial, gps

I am working on a project where I connect a GPS module and GPRS SIM900 shield. The location will be sent when it recives a certain character.

Now my question is, can the Arduino receive from GPRS and GPS module data at the same time? The GPS is not given coordinates, however it works properly without receiving a message from the GPRS.

I am using softwareserial  for both. Should/can I use hardware serial and softwareserial?

Comment: You cannot receive from two softwareserial devices at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using `SoftwareSerial` for both.

As others have said, you cannot listen to 2 `SoftwareSerial` ports at the same time.

> Should/can I use `HardwareSerial` and `SoftwareSerial`?
>
> ... can the Arduino receive from GPRS and GPS module data at the same time?

Yes, but...

[This answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34126#34130) provides full details on choosing "good" combinations of hardware and software serial ports.  To summarize:

- Use the `HardwareSerial` port (i.e., `Serial`) for one of the devices.  You can still use it for debug prints, as long as the device has some kind of command "format".  For example, if commands start with "AT", just make sure that none of your debug prints start with "AT".  It is the absolute best choice.  You would have to disconnect RX pin 0 from the device in order to upload new sketches over USB.
- Use `AltSoftSerial` for the other device.  It is the most efficient software serial port, and it can be used at the same time as `Serial`.  It only works on two specific pins.
- `NeoSWSerial` is the next best choice, at limited baud rates.  It can be used with the above choices, but transmitting on `NeoSWSerial` prevents them from receiving.
- `SoftwareSerial` is the worst choice.  Receiving **or** transmitting on `SoftwareSerial` prevents all of the above from receiving anything.  It disables interrupts for long periods of time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't need to use both GPS and GPRS in same time. Just check for a certain character from GPRS in the loop and when it comes check the GPS data.

Why not connect GPS module to hardware serial?

Answer (score 0):

you can connect gps to hardware serial port rx and gsm to software serial.  in similar way,  I solve the problem