# Alternative Rx/Tx Pins for Arduino Uno and Pro Mini

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, rx-pin

Do they have specific pins that is best to be use as Rx/Tx pins (aside from D0 and D1)? If so, what makes them special?

edit: What pin feature i should look out for when choosing the rx/tx pin? Is there any specific pins that will make it a better rx/tx pin?

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34126/whats-the-difference-between-all-the-software-serial-libraries-which-one-is-ar

Answer (score 2):

Pins `D0` and `D1` are used for *hardware serial*, see [`Serial`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/) library reference.

You can use any other pins for virtual Rx/Tx lines employing a *software serial* mode, for example by using the `SoftwareSerial` library, see [Software Serial example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample), or by implementing your own custom code, or custom library.

Comment: for Mega and Leonardo, there are other recommended pins for rx/tx. do they have it on uno?

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino SoftwareSerial library can use any pair of pins.

[AltSoftSerial](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_AltSoftSerial.html) uses special pins. AltSoftSerial uses a 16 bit hardware timer to generate the transmit output and measure the receive input waveforms. The timer works on pins 8 and 9 on Uno and Atmega 328p boards.

Comment: thanks. So this is alternative library to software serial is it. i will read about it first.