# Using SoftwareSerial library with EnableInterrupt

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, softwareserial

I'm working on a project that involves both serial communication and GSM transmission.
I'm using the SoftwareSerial library for RS232 communication, and GSM (SMS) transmission:

- TX and RX for RS232 : Arduino Uno D3 and D4 pins
- TX and RX for GSM module : Arduino Uno D7 and D8 pins

The project requires also the use of the EnableInterrupt library to enable interrupt in Arduino's analog pins, meaning that I DON'T USE EnableInterrupt for all of the Arduino's digital pins including D3, D4, D7 and D8.

However when running the program that includes the two libraries, this long error message shows up :

```
libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `SoftwareSerial::read()':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_3'

sketch\sketch_jun14a.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `SoftwareSerial::read()':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_5'

sketch\sketch_jun14a.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `SoftwareSerial::read()':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_4'

sketch\sketch_jun14a.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Erreur de compilation pour la carte Arduino/Genuino Uno
```

Clearly, there is a conflict between the two libraries, Is there any solution to remove this conflict and run the two libraries together ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: With SoftwareSerial, you can use only one RX at a time. Could you replace the Arduino Uno with a Arduino Mega 2560 ? That one has 3 spare hardware serial ports.

Answer (score 1):

- SoftwareSerial uses *all* PinChange interrupts.
- EnableInterrupts uses *all* PinChange interrupts.

You can see the conflict.

All you can do is to modify *both* libraries to remove support for the interrupts you don't need it to support - that way you share out the responsibility for handling the different interrupts between the two libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using different software serial libraries and pins.  To apply [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/26240#26277), I would suggest this configuration:

- Connect your RS232 device to pins 0 & 1 and use `Serial`
- Connect your GSM device to pins 8 & 9 and use `AltSoftSerial` (it must use those pins).

If you do not send anything *to* the RS232 device, you can still use `Serial` for debug statements.  Don't even connect the TX pin to the RS232 device.  You will have to disconnect the RX pin to upload new sketches over USB.  Or, if the RS232 device receives formatted commands, it would ignore debug statments that don't look like commands.  This has the added benefit that the Serial Monitor window will display the commands you do send to the RS232 device.

If you *really* need to use 3 serial ports, you will have to use this configuration:

- Use `Serial` for whatever
- Connect the RS232 or GSM device to pins 8 & 9 and use `AltSoftSerial`
- Connect the other device to any two pins and use my [NeoSWSerial](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoSWSerial).

`AltSoftSerial` is more efficient at transmitting than `NeoSWSerial`, so use `AltSoftSerial` for the device to which you send the most data.  `NeoSWSerial` is limited to baud rates 9600, 19200 and 38400, so that may be a consideration.

`SoftwareSerial` is a terrible choice, because it disables interrupts for long periods of time, it can only listen to one port at a time, and it cannot transmit and receive at the same time.

`AltSoftSerial` and `NeoSWSerial` do not have these limitations, and they can co-exist to give you 2 extra serial ports.  You should also be aware the `NeoSWSerial` disables interrupts while transmitting (not receiving).  `AltSoftSerial` uses one of the TIMER resources, while `NeoSWSerial` simply uses the `millis()` timer.

#### ADDENDUM

To answer your original question about using the `EnableInterrupt` library at the same time as a software serial library:

If you are using the first configuration above, `AltSoftSerial` will not conflict with `EnableInterrupt`.

If you are using the second configuration, `NeoSWSerial` **will** conflict with `EnableInterrupt`.  For this possibility, `NeoSWSerial` has an option to disable using all the Pin Change Interrupt ISRs.  Uncomment [this line](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoSWSerial/blob/master/src/NeoSWSerial.h#L108) and call the NeoSWSerial::rxISR from the appropriate `enableInterrupt()` callback function:

```
#include <NeoSWSerial.h>
NeoSWSerial oneDevice( RX_PIN, TX_PIN );

void myISR()
{
  NeoSWSerial::rxISR( *portInputRegister( digitalPinToPort( RX_PIN ) ) );
}

void setup()
{
  enableInterrupt( RX_PIN, myISR, CHANGE );
}
```

This puts `EnableInterrupt` in charge of the ISRs.  If you want to try `NeoSWSerial`, it is available from the Arduino IDE Library Manager, under the menu **Sketch -> Include Library -> Manage Libraries**.